# Retrive data from Desktop Sqlite DB to android app via Wifi Lan connection

Tags: c#, android, sqlite

I am developing a android app and windows app, where i have to pull data from desktop saved Sqlite database to android apps.

I have tried by sharing folder but nothinh worked.

```
txtipaddress.Text = "100.85.138.330";


private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       myBuilder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder()
       {
           DataSource = @"\\\\" + txtipaddress.Text + @"\qscanDBAttacheds\test.s3db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;"
       };

       SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(myBuilder.ConnectionString);
       con.Open();
       MessageBox.Show("Success");
   }
```

What i want is, i just update data of DB from desktop and by click can see those rows data in android app for futher actions.

Comment: Do you get an exception thrown? What does happen?

Comment: invalid connection.. this is happening...

Comment: A sqlite database is a file. You can't connect to it over a network because there's no database server to connect to. You should use a different dbms that does support that kind of connection or completely rethink your approach.